# Drawing a circle on a canvas with HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

I'm having an issue at the moment with adding a circle to a canvas.
I am required to make a graph. I have added the x and y axis' to the canvas and 
need to add circles to act as points on the graph.

Code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  

<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>

<body onload="drawGraph()" >
    <div id="main">
        <canvas id="theCanvas" width="1100" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function drawGraph () {

//Access the canvas using the ID & set the context:
var a = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
var context = a.getContext("2d");


context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.lineWidth = 3;

//Draw Y Axis:
context.moveTo(50,50);
context.lineTo(50,325);
context.stroke();

//Draw X Axis:
context.moveTo(49,325);
context.lineTo(980,325);
context.stroke();

//"Draw" text for the days of the week on the canvas:
context.font = "15px Arial";
context.fillText("Monday",60,360);
context.fillText("Tuesday",200,360);
context.fillText("Wednesday",340,360);
context.fillText("Thursday",500,360);
context.fillText("Friday",640,360);
context.fillText("Saturday",780,360);
context.fillText("Sunday",920,360);
context.strokeText();


}
</script>
```

I have tried drawing a circle with the arc method with something like this:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(50,325,20,0,2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();
```

which doesn't make anything appear on my canvas.

As far as I can establish online, this is the standard way to do this.

Am I doing something wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a last argument, a Boolean indicating if the angle should be calculated counterclockwise or clockwise:

> context.arc(50,325,20,0,2*Math.PI,false);

Comment: The last parameter is optional and defaults to false.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing arguments for the `strokeText` method:

```
context.strokeText();
```

should be:

```
context.strokeText(txt, x, y);
```

Since they are missing the script will fail and stop not executing anything after it:
**[A demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/n29AR/)**

`fillText()` and `strokeText()` does not add to the path however, so you need to draw the same text again if you want an outline of it on top.

Besides from that the `arc` is correct as you do it. You could add a `closePath()` before stroking it though.